# Where can i store my website data?

Tags: html, datastore

So i have a simple website with 3 .html pages in it (index, about and products). Each page can have different backgrounds (a picture or just colored). Index is a simple page just with a background and logo, about contents **about text** and products page contents products as so: **picture - description of product(just text), pic - desrc and so on..**.

I want to make an admin panel for this website, where user can change backgrounds for these pages, about text and change/add/remove products to/from the products page.

Changing these pages through admin panel would be too complicated i think. Using for example MySQL for one some text and for example 10 products (There will be ~10 products on the page) is too much (but if i will not find out a better way, i will use this one). Storing all data in some file on server ? Maybe i should do it this way ? But i`m not sure how to do it properly. Now i think that xml would be the best option for me. Is that so ? Thank you.

Comment: Why `xml`? I do not see what that has to do with the issue at hand. Anyways: you need some persistent storage, so you need either a database or a file strategy. As a database sqlite might be an alternative, easier to setup than mysql but slower. If you use a file based approach, then the format of the files is not that important I'd say...

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i`ll think then about SQLLite

Comment: If you really want to use that as a selling platform, why do you make all that effort? Use something proven and easy to use instead, a web page toolbox. I recommend jimdo (jimdo.com), they offer a shop module too.

Answer (score 1):

For a site that small, an admin panel would be more work than it would be worth. However, if you are selling things - shopify has a nice panel - and WordPress is free - but you sound like you are pretty new to writing code... so - maybe you should just get a simple hosting plan and put your 3 .html pages there.

This is a little outdated - but a good tutorial for beginners wanting to use WordPress (which uses mySQL)

http://www.lynda.com/Chris-Coyier/725506-1.html

Comment: I`m not so new and this is not my site. I dont think that i want to use some frameworks for this site..